# Get xaml directory path at design time

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, workflow-foundation

I have a workflow with multiple activities that I'm editing on VS2017. This workflow is here:
`C:/Repo/Workflows/ProjectXyz/Foo/ThisFile.xaml`

This workflow is populated with activities, one of those activities is of type `MyPathActivity`. This activity has a button. When that button is clicked (on design time from `ThisFile.xaml`), I want it to show a `MessageBox` with the text `C:/Repo/Workflows/ProjectXyz/Foo/ThisFile.xaml`, but I don't know how to get that path.

**How can I get the path to the xaml file at design time?**

All that I've tried got me to the VS debugger path, the project's root path,... but I need the full path to the xaml that I'm editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get the xaml path:

We point to the `EditingContext` (`Context` property of the `ActivityDesigner`) and then to its `Items` property. Those items are a collection of ContextItems of these types:

- ReadOnlyState
- AssemblyContextControlItem
- WorkflowCommandExtensionItem
- **WorkflowFileItem**
- Selection

Now **`WorkflowFileItem`** sound a lot like something that would be useful =)

Pointing to the property **`LoadedFile`** of that item we get:

```
C:/Repo/Workflows/ProjectXyz/Foo/ThisFile.xaml
```

Hurray!

---

Now the code:

```
public static class DesignerUtils
{
    public static string GetXamlPathFromActivityDesignerElement<TActivityDesigner
        (TActivityDesigner designer) where TActivityDesigner : ActivityDesigner
    {
        EditingContext editingContext = designer.Context;
        ContextItemManager items = editingContext.Items;
        WorkflowFileItem fileItem = (WorkflowFileItem)items
            .SingleOrDefault(item => item is WorkflowFileItem);

        return fileItem.LoadedFile;
    }
}
```

Here the use in the click handler:

```
public void OnPathButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string xamlPath = DesignerUtils
        .GetXamlPathFromActivityDesignerElement<MyPathActivityDesigner>
        (sender as FrameworkElement);
    MessageBox.Show(xamlPath);
}
```

---

**Edit:** First version needed the event sender. That is a totally unnecesary step, because we already have the designer using `this`